# Adding text periodically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run small snippet code in JavaScript, where I want to write on the web page simple hello world each 5 seconds. I think it must be ok, but no, still I got only first hello world and no more. Could you give me a hand in this? Thanks

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var i=0;

 function startTimer() {

    window.setTimeout('refresh()',5000);
 }

 function refresh() {

 document.write("Hello world "+i+"<br/>");
 i++;
 window.setTimeout('startTimer()',1);
 } 

 startTimer();
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: As Amar Palsapure has noted in this answer, the root cause of the problem was the use of `document.write`. In my demonstration, I use a `p` element to `document.body.appendChild()` to add the text to the screen.

You can use `setTimeout()`, but you have to make it contingent on the last `setTimeout()` that ran; so that each time the caller runs, it creates the next timeout.

`setInterval()` is designed to run at a "regular" interval (neither `setTimeout()` nor `setInterval()` are truly reliable in when they run); however, if the calls to `setInterval()` get backed up due to some other process blocking it's execution (Javascript is single-threaded), you could have issues with those queued callbacks. That's why I prefer the approach I have below.

Note, refrain from the `setTimeout('funcCalled()', 100)` usage; this is running an `eval()` on that string you're passing in, which can change the scope in which you're running the callback, as well as being considered "evil" due to security issues related to `eval()`. You're best to avoid it altogether.

**EDIT** - Modified slightly.

I have made some changes to the approach. See my comments.

```
// The first and last lines comprise a self-executing,
// anonymous function, eg, (function(){})();.
// This allows me to use a local function scope and not the
// global window scope, while still maintaining my variables
// due to it being a "closure" (function(){}).
(function(){
    var i = 0,
        timer = 5000,
        // I'm just going to add this to the DOM.
        text = document.createElement('p'); 

    // This is a variable function, meaning it stores a 
    // reference to a function.
    var helloWorld = function() {
        // Here is where I add the Hello World statement
        text.innerHTML += 'Hello World! Loop: ' + i++ + '<br/>';
        // Them add it to the DOM.
        document.body.appendChild(text);

        // I added this so it wouldn't run forever.
        if (i < 100) {
            // A setTimeout() will be added each time the last
            // was run, as long as i < 100.
            // Note how I handle the callback, which is the
            // first argument in the function call.
            setTimeout(helloWorld, timer);
        }

        // I added the change so it wouldn't take so long 
        // to see if was working.
        timer = 500;
    }

    // Here I use a variable function and attach it to the
    // onload page event, so it will run when the page is
    // done loading.
    window.onload = helloWorld;
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tXFrf/2/

Comment: This code is working because, `document.append` is used and that too with help of `p` element. In question `document.write` is used, if it is used here, this code will also not work.

Comment: Yes, you're right; that was the primary issue with the code as it was posted.

Answer (score 1):

**The main issue is `document.write`**. There is nothing wrong with `setTimeout` or rest of the code.

> The reason it does not work is that once document.write is called the first time, it overwrites your existing code of setTimeout() and since there is no code so it will not work.
>   What you need to do is use some other means to write the value in the page, certainly no `document.write`...

Instead of using `setInterval` use `setTimeout`.

You can try this

```
<html>
   <body>
    <div id="clock" ></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var i = 0,
         timerHandle,
         clock;

      function startTimer() {
          clock = document.getElementById('clock');
          //You can use timerHandle, to stop timer by doing clearInterval(timerHandle)  
          timerHandle = self.setInterval(funRefresh, 2000);
      }

      var funRefresh = function refresh() { 
         clock.innerHTML += "Hello world " + i++ + "<br/>";
      } 
      startTimer();
    </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but when I added this code to my test page, it still shows only Hello World 0, nothing more :-( With refresh, I am trying to write rows containing Hello World and i each time incremented. So output should be Hello World 0, after 5sec newline and Hello World 1 ...

Comment: Comment `window.setTimeOut` in `refresh` function. Let me try on jsFiddle.net

Comment: Commented, still having the same issue

Comment: `setTimeout()` could work as well, just depends on how you use it. See my answer for an example (although `setInterval()` does make sense as well here).

Comment: There is some issue. When you use `document.write`, next `setinterval` gets cleared. If you use `div` and append data to the `div` it will work.

Comment: You only need one approach: Either a `setInterval()` or self-spawning `setTimeout()`s.

Comment: You also don't have a reference to `#clock`. Using only `setInterval()`: http://jsfiddle.net/GJLeq/

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to, but `clock` is never defined in your code; it's a not a reference to a `DOM` node. When I view that fiddle you linked, I get `clock is not defined` in Firebug. This runs just fine [once you add `document.getElementById('clock')`](http://jsfiddle.net/GJLeq/2/).

Comment: I have tested on IE, and it works. But `document.getElementById` is better way. Will update the answer.

Comment: I see; that's truly bad design on Microsoft's part to populate global references to elements based on an `id` attribute. I know it doesn't work in Firefox and I would bet also Chrome, Safari, Opera, etc. I'd definitely avoid using that shortcut.

Comment: I will give you an upvote if you replace the `'refresh()'` with a variable or inline anonymous function. Also, since you run the `clock = document.getElementById('clock')` after the `<div id="clock"></div>` in the page load, you can set that variable when you declare it instead of within the `startTimer()` function. I kept `startTimer()` in my demonstration only because I was using `window.onload` and `#clock` wouldn't be available at the time the code was run. Otherwise, you don't need `startTimer()`, just setup the `setInterval(refresh, 2000)`.

Comment: For instance: http://jsfiddle.net/WnTfM/ (Or with a limit of 10 loops: http://jsfiddle.net/WnTfM/2/)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer. But OP hasn't accepted any of the solution. I hope Waypoint issue is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/NC6N5/1/)

```
    var i = 0;

function startTimer() {
    window.setInterval(refresh, 5000);
}

function refresh() {
    document.write("Hello world " + i + "<br/>");
    i++;

   // window.setTimeout(startTimer,1);
}

startTimer();​
```

Comment: A `setTimeout()` and a `setInterval()`? This is going to run amok after too long.

Comment: I had made the code working. Anyways, I have commented out setTimeout which was there in the initial code.